# Regex in Express route not matching

Tags: regex, node.js, express

Do regular expressions in Express routing work the same as normal Javascript regexs? I am trying to match routes that look like either "/users" or "/blah/users"

I also want to capture the blah part if it exists. I came up with this regular expression to do the job:

```
/^(?:\/)(?:(\w+)(?:\/))?(?:\busers\b)$/
```

I tested the regex here and it works fine:

https://regex101.com/r/zS3nH5/2

However, when I put it into my app.get route it never matches:

```
app.get('/^(?:\/)(?:(\w+)(?:\/))?(?:\busers\b)$/', function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: That's because what you have there isn't a regex, it's a string.

Comment: Try remove the `'` outside your regex?